# save informations in a data base and getting the id sql server c#

Tags: c#, sql-server

It's my first time working with SQL Server and I can't find a helpful tutorial. I am trying to get information from the UI (infos about a contact) and save it to the database (localdb in Visual Studio) then I'd like to get the id of the added contact. I use the following code:

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source = (LocalDB)\\MSSQLLocalDB; AttachDbFilename = E:\\c#\\contact2\\contact2\\contactbase.mdf;Integrated Security=True");
String query = "INSERT INTO contacts(Nom,Adresse,Tel,Email,Sweb) output Inseted.Id_Contact VALUES ('" + contact.Text + "','" + adr.Text + "','" + tlphn.Text + "','" + mail.Text + "','" + site.Text + "')";
con.Open();
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con);
int id = 0;
id = (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
if (con.State == System.Data.ConnectionState.Open)
{
    con.Close();
}
```

But it's not working, I get this exeption:

{"The multi-part identifier \"Inseted.Id_Contact\" could not be bound."}

and I don't know how to fix it.

Remark: there's is an auto_incrment for the id could you help me please

Comment: `Inseted` ?  Typo?

Comment: (Side note: Your code is *wide open* to **SQL injection**.)

Comment: You're also not handling your connections properly, leaking resources. Make sure you learn about [IDisposable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.idisposable(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: **Warning!!!** Code is opened to SQL Injection

Answer (score 0):

It should be output Inserted.Id_Contact ,in your code has a spelling mistake on Inserted

INSERT INTO contacts(Nom,Adresse,Tel,Email,Sweb) output Inserted.Id_Contact VALUES ('" + contact.Text + "','" + adr.Text + "','" + tlphn.Text + "','" + mail.Text + "','" + site.Text + "')";